Too many results returned from SQL query
There are four tables: Attributes, Place_Attributes, Place_Categories, and Categories.

I need to join Attributes and Place_Attributes on AttributeId and select Name.
I need to join Categories and Place_Categories on CategoryId and select Name.
I need to join these two lists of results on PlaceId from the Place_Attributes and Place_Categories tables.

The query runs and I get a list of results. I thought the list was correct, but on closer inspection, the list of attributes being returned is longer than the list I was expecting. It does not match what is live on the site. I'm positive it's my query that's wrong. The live site is correct.
I tried many different queries and the below query is the closest to what I need, but results in the above problem. Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong, here?
Here is a sample of the Place_Attributes table:



id
PlaceId
AttributeId




27849
200712
84


24892
200009
134


15453
200091
156


41542
202022
62


72485
200475
65



Here is a sample of the Place_Categories table:



id
PlaceId
CategoryId




138072
200712
48


815474
200009
36


124543
200091
90


81487
202022
1


548425
200475
4



Here is a sample of the Attributes table:



id
Name




65
Pool


62
Publicly Owned


84
Rental


134
Lift Fees


156
Lift Type



Here is a sample of the Categories table:



id
Name




1
Amusement Parks


4
Local


90
Hotels


48
Campgrounds


36
Cabins



Here is the query I tried:
DECLARE @TempResults TABLE (
    attributename VARCHAR(255),
    categoryname VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO @TempResults (attributename, categoryname)
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.name AS attributename,
    c.name AS categoryname
FROM Attributes a
INNER JOIN Place_Attributes pa ON a.id = pa.attributeid
INNER JOIN Place_Categories pc ON pa.PlaceId = pc.placeid
INNER JOIN Categories c ON pc.CategoryId = c.id;

SELECT * FROM @TempResults
ORDER BY categoryname;

These are the results I got using the above query. The problem is I'm getting too many records. Some of these attributes aren't actually associated with the categoryname of Amusement Parks:



attributename
categoryname




Pool
Amusement Parks


Publicly Owned
Amusement Parks


Rental
Amusement Parks


Lift fees
Amusement Parks


Lift type
Amusement Parks



These are the expected results:



attributename
categoryname




Pool
Amusement Parks


Publicly Owned
Amusement Parks


Lift type
Amusement Parks




Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question.

They are also the results I'm looking for, but without the extra data in the attributename column: what extra data? Best to show what you need and what you are getting separately for clarity.

@DaleK I’ve put that information above in the original explanation of the problem. However, I added it at the bottom as well. I’ve put as much information as I I can for this question. Would it be possible for someone to read the query and tell me if it doesn’t match my intended  results? Thank you!

"They are also the results I'm looking for, but without the extra data"  Your result only has 2 columns.  What's the extra data?

You've explained that you are getting some extra data, but you haven't explained which data is extra. And it much much easier to show your expected results than to "explain" them - well much much easier to understand.

@Eric The extra results are that there are too many attributes linked to certain categories. They aren't correctly matched. In the example above, AmusementParks should have attributes of, Pool, PubliclyOwned, and Lift Type but not Rental and Lift Fees. These final two attributes weren't selected to be linked to categories.

@DaleK The comment to Eric explains what I mean. I have edited my question again to show the results I got using the query and then the expected results.

I'm flat out today, but if you created your example as a DBFiddle I would take a look.

Thank you @DaleK. This is a work-related question on billable hours at an agency. Unfortunately, I've used up more time than I should have posting and tweaking this on SO. Next time I'll start with DBFiddle and hopefully it will go over better. I appreciate the offer!

Your example is not consistent. There is no way the example data you provided would produce that result (for one, your example data doesn't even include the attributes you specify.

@MarkRotteveel These are all samples of the full tables and results. All are huge. The tables are huge, the results list is in the tens of thousands. I don't know how to provide a reproducible example when I'm working with this much data. I've listened to the comments and tweaked this question multiple times to provide what was requested. Still, there are no ideas that would help me in any way. Focusing on the query itself and what I want returned, does it make sense how I'm joining these tables or is there an issue there? I would really appreciate help on this.

The point is, that if you provide example data, then the expected results and the actual results should be consistent with that example data, and currently it is not.

@MarkRotteveel In response to your comment, I edited the question again to relate all the data.

Here is a fiddle containing your data and query. The actual results do not match your post (each row has a different CategoryName value.). However, I see no indication why the results would be any different. You have five PlaceIds. Each has a distinct attribute and a distinct category. The expected results would be five distinct combinations.
